# Can't get all images from facebook album using fb graph api with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, fs

I am learning nodejs.
I tried to download all my photos from Mobile uploads album.
I used 'fb' npm module for graph api. I am only getting 25 photos but in my album  there are 300+ photos.
How can I get all photos?

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var request = require('request');
var FB = require('fb');
var fs = require('fs');

var my_token = "xyz";
FB.setAccessToken(mt_token);
var urls = [];

FB.api('/me/albums','get',  function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
   console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
   return;
  }
  var data = _.findWhere(res.data, {name:"Mobile Uploads"});
  FB.api('/'+data.id+'/photos', 'get', (resp) => {
       if(!resp || resp.error) {
   console.log(!resp ? 'error occurred' : resp.error);
   return;
  }
resp.data.forEach(function(element) {
    urls.push(element.source);
});

for(var i = 0;i<urls.length;i++){
    request(urls[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('img/'+i+'.jpg'));
    console.log("Downloaded : "+i+'.jpg');
}

  });
});
```

[image]
Thanx

Comment: Yes indeed only 25 fields are returned. To get the next you have to manage with the paging cursors before and after.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: I didn't know about paging. thanx

Comment: i am getting a infinite loop of same 25 elements
Can you provide me the code for paging to get all photos.

Comment: help me with my code [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/FfEkpzyF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got it using `request` module facebook api did not work for me

```
function downloadLoop(urls) {
            for(i;i<urls.length;i++){
                request(urls[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('img/'+(i+1)+'.jpg')).on('finish', function(response) {         
                    console.log("Download Completed : "+(++j)+'/'+i);
                    });

            }
}

function download(next) {
        request({
            url: next,
            json: true
        }, function(err, res, body) {
            if(err) throw err;
            for (var i = 0; i < body.data.length; i++) {
                urls.push(body.data[i].images[0].source);                           
            }
            console.log("getting images... Total Image : "+ urls.length);
            if(body.paging && body.paging.next) {
             download(body.paging.next);

        } else {
                console.log("Completed");
            }
downloadLoop(urls);
        });
}
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/MaxySpark/fb-photo-album-download)